# How to clone an element and append to a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

I have a page that has a couple image thumbnails that when clicked on they get cloned and appended into another element. The issue that I'm running in to is that all of the elements that I need to `appendTo` all have the same class. So if I click one thumbnail it gets appended to every single element that has the class `view_full_img`. Here is the HTML that I have to work with. Simply targeting these with different classes is not going to work for me, this HTML is generated by Drupal.

```
<div class="view_full_img"></div>
<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="img blue"></div>
    <div class="img green"></div>
    <div class="img yellow"></div>
</div>

<div class="view_full_img"></div>
<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="img red"></div>
    <div class="img purple"></div>
    <div class="img orange"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery..

```
$(".thumbs div").click(function(){
    $(".view_full_img div").remove();
    $(this).clone().appendTo(".view_full_img");
});
```

What I want to have happen is that when I click one of the `.thumbs` divs I want it to get cloned into the `.view_full_img` div that is directly above it. I've tried using combinations of `closest()` `prev()` `parent()` etc and just can't come up with something that works.

Here's a jsfiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/UeTv6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".thumbs div").click(function () {
    var t = $(this);
    t.appendTo(t.parent().prev(".view_full_img"));
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r64nq/)

Answer (score 1):

You need `parent()`, then `prev()`:

```
$(".thumbs div").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().prev(".view_full_img").empty().append($(this).clone());
});
```